# How to show a message from webmethod?

Tags: c#, message, webmethod

Friends,I need a help regarding showing error message or any other message in web method. I tried with writing some function to show message if the return value is "0" or the return string variable's length is "0" but no result. Can you give some solution to this?
Yes, sure. Here is my code:-

```
    [WebMethod]
public string[] GetCompletionCompany(string prefixText, int count)
{
    if (count == 0)
    {
        count = 10;
    }

    if (prefixText != "")
    {
        strSQLQuery = "SELECT ID," +
                    "       stallno," +
                    "       company " +
                    "FROM   IESS2012_IND_PartDetails " +
                    "WHERE company LIKE '%" + prefixText + "%' " +
                    "ORDER BY company";
    }
    DataTable dt = objDBHelper.gReturnDataSet(System.Data.CommandType.Text, strSQLQuery).Tables[0];
    List<string> items = new List<string>(count);

    for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        string strName = dt.Rows[i][2].ToString();
        items.Add(strName);
    }

    if (items.ToArray().Length == 0)
    {
        ShowMessage();
        return items.ToArray();
    }
    else
    {
        return items.ToArray();
    }

}

    private void ShowMessage()
{

    string msg= gUserMessage.NoRecords;
    return msg;
}
```

How will I show the message that there is no record?

Comment: Can we see what you said you tried ?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to show the Error Message on Client Side you can just throw an appropriate Exception - SOAP will encapsulate it and you get a SOAP-Error on the client side containing the exception message.

So on the Server side:

```
if (items.ToArray().Length == 0)
{
    throw new NoRecordsException("Your Message...");
}
```

and on the client side (assuming you are using C# too):

```
string[] result;
try
{
    result = service.GetCompletionCompany(prefixText, count);
}
catch(SoapException exp)
{
    string message = exp.Message; //or exp.InnerException.Message
}
```

Comment: @Sukanya: I added a small example out of my head - I'm not shure if its 100% correct, but it should point you in the right direction...